# unable to test alexa skills on https://alexaweb.herokuapp.com/

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am a newbie on alexa (aws). 
I just want to test alexa features on https://alexaweb.herokuapp.com/. 
I have not developped any skill yet.
Alexa is not reponding me on this site. I don't know if I have to develop a skill or because my accent with is not english native.

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: Try echosim.io or reverb android/iOS app

Comment: I did it. How i want to understand if i should have my own skills to test it or not. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: Once you've `log in with amazon` in echosim.io, go to alexa.amazon.com to browse skills and enable those. If you have developed any skills, those will be shown in `Your Skills` section.